# Parse Database not cleared on logout Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, usersession

As the question says, I'm having a problem when logging out from parse. If I login to another account, the old data is still in the DB. 
My question is, do I need to clear it manually ? I mean, calling ParseObject.unpinAll() ?

FYI, the app doesn't have the user annonymous enabled. (I think it's disabled by default, right ?)

What approach should I take?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out to be the solution I commented on the question, I call `ParseObject.unpinAll()` and it's good to go.

Thanks